# Unable to generate thumbnail for video iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Im trying to generate a thumbnail for a video chosen using the imagePicker, yet i am receiving this error

```
  "[discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
```

UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
", can someone help me figure out why?

below are some snippets from my code.

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
var videoURL: NSURL?
@IBOutlet weak var videoImageTemp: UIImageView!
```

This function is being used to start the process of instantiating the imagePickerController

```
@IBAction func addVideo(_ sender: Any) {

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
     let asset = AVAsset(url: info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as! URL)
        let assetImgGenerate : AVAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let time = CMTimeMake(1, 2)
        let img = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        if img != nil {
            let frameImg  = UIImage(cgImage: img!)
                self.videoImageTemp.image = frameImg
                self.videoImageTemp.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                // assign your image to UIImageView
    }
    imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Your video url is a temporary file url. The file will be deleted as soon as the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method finishes. BTW not related to your issue but you are supposed to use `URL` instead of `NSURL` since Swift 3

Comment: How do I fix this? The temporary file url?

Comment: do it in the main thread inside that method or save/move it to a directory in your APP sandbox like document directory

Comment: I tried to use DispatchQueue.main.async to do it on the main thread, but it still didnt work. am I missing something? I updated the Question aswell

Comment: No need to use `DispatchQueue` at all just add the code to your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method which it already runs in the main thread naturally

Comment: Im sorry, Im alittle confused because I thought I was already using the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method?

Comment: yes but you are dispatching it to the global queue, change that method declaration and make it return the image synchronously `func previewImageFromVideo(url: URL) -> UIImage {`

Comment: Btw don use `try?` it will ignore the error. Use `do try catch` and print it. And  `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` is deprecated. You should use `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`  and no need to use double quotes around it

Comment: I have posted how you should create a video thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

Your video url is a temporary file url. The file will be deleted as soon as the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method finishes. BTW not related to your issue but you are supposed to use URL instead of NSURL since Swift 3. And you need to do it in the main thread inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method`, change previewImageFromVideo method declaration and make it return the resulting image synchronously and make it throws `func previewImageFromVideo(url: URL) throws -> CGImage`. Your code should look like this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
            imageView.image = getVideoThumbFrom(url: url)
        }
    } else {
        if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
            imageView.image = getVideoThumbFrom(url: url)
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        print("picker dismissed")
    }
}
```

---

```
func getVideoThumbFrom(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        return try UIImage(cgImage: previewImageFromVideo(url: url))
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

---

```
func previewImageFromVideo(url: URL) throws -> CGImage {
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: AVAsset(url: url))
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    return try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(1, 2), actualTime: nil)
}
```

---

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oefb9rxbs5kt7nj/AADXJc0OGtQPl7sUk5q3wIvua?dl=1)